# cakephp 3 locale not working on live side

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, locale

Hello I have cakephp 3 app which has option to change language on settings page.
and i have created locale folder in src/locale/fr/default.po

**Thing is,it works on local side but on live side it doesnt work.**

**Here is the function i added to change language dynamically.**

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
use Cake\I18n\Time;

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $session = $this->request->session();

            $this->loadComponent("APPFunction");
            $lang = $this->GYMFunction->getSettings("sys_language");        
            if (empty($lang)) {
                return;
            }
            I18n::locale($lang);

    }
```

[Click to see locale list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMfD6.png)

There are the locales i have added in locale folder.

Whats wrong m i doin? is there anything about permissions?  Locale folder has 0755 permissions and .po has 644 permissions.

Comment: The folder has to be named `Locale`, with an uppercase `L`.

Comment: thnx.I changes to Locale.But still its not working. Please help i need to fix it as urgently.

Comment: Its working now.May be it takes time to reflect on server. Thanks